# Firebase Anonymously authentication won work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a picture to firebase storage and the take picture is in the form of a bitmap. But I don't want any authentication at all so I have followed the Firebase tutorial on anonymous login. When running the app I don't get any errors but the picture won't upload. I don't really care if the picture taking part is perfect, right now I want to focus on the uploading onto Firebase.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    ImageView imageView;
    Button btnOpen;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        btnOpen = findViewById(R.id.btn_open);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            }, 100);
        }


        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        Log.e("USER", currentUser.toString());
    }


    public void signInAnonymously() {
        mAuth.signInAnonymously()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("TAG", "signInAnonymously:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("TAG", "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());

                        }

                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            assert data != null;
            Bitmap takenImage = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(data.getExtras()).get("data");

            signInAnonymously();
//            saveImage(takenImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(takenImage);

        }

    }

    private void saveImage(Bitmap inBitmap) {
        long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        String ts = Long.toString(tsLong);

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://savephototest.appspot.com");
        StorageReference mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child(ts + ".jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        UploadTask uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(data);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
                Log.d("downloadUrl-->", "" + downloadUrl);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend changing `StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://savephototest.appspot.com")` to `StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference()` This will take the configuration out of your `FirebaseApp` instance, which typically means it comes out of the `google-services.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the upload of the image before the sign-in (which happens asynchronously) completes. So if you have security rules on storage that the user is signed in before they can upload, that means the write will be rejected.

Since you're leaving `onFailure` empty, you won't see that error. So the first step to verify if this is happening is to not ignore the error, but surface it. For example with:

```
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
  throw exception;
}
```

---

If this is indeed the cause of the problem, you'll need to ensure that the upload only starts after the sign-in has been completed.

A very quick way to do that is to move the call to `saveImage` into the method that signs in:

```
public void signInAnonymouslyAndUpload() {
    mAuth.signInAnonymously()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "signInAnonymously:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    saveImage(takenImage);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w("TAG", "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        assert data != null;
        Bitmap takenImage = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(data.getExtras()).get("data");

        signInAnonymouslyAndUpload();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(takenImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've made the edits that you suggested but it seems that there is an issue in the anonymously sign in function because I don't get any of the logs neither the success or failure in the onComplete function.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` and run in the debugger, does it reach that breakpoint?

Comment: Yes and I've also tried with onFailure and onCanceldListener and put breakpoints inside of them but none of them yields anything. So I'm guessing there is a problem with my Firebase connection but when looking inside the Firebase assistant in the android studio it says that my app I connect and cloud storage is setup.